# Finding the next power of 2 for a negative number

Tags: c++, math

Hey guys I was doing research on calculating the next power of two and stumbled on a code that looks like this:

```
int x;//assume that x is already initialized with a value
--x;
x |= x >> 1;
x |= x >> 2;
x |= x >> 4;
x |= x >> 8;
x |= x >> 16;
return x+1;
```

It works fine when I run with positive numbers but it doesn't work with negative numbers which I dont understand because I think it should not matter whether or not a number is positive or negative in terms of finding the next power of two for it. If we have the number 5 and we want to find the next power of 2. If we think about it intuitively we know that its 8 because 8 is bigger than 5 and 8 is the same as 2^3. If I try using a negative number I always keep getting 0 which I don't understand because 0 is not a power of two

Comment: Bitwise operations are not really designed to work with negative numbers. Do you understand how the code works for non-negative numbers?

Comment: int is a signed integer.

Comment: @SergeyA I understand how the code works for non negative number but I don't understand why this won't work with a negative number

Comment: Take a look at [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). That's how negative numbers are stored and explains why bit-shifting doesn't work on them.

Comment: @user6421091, ok, do you know how negative numbers are represented on your platform?

Comment: @Frecklefoot, technically wrong. This is how negative numbers **usually are stored**. There is nothing in C++ standard which prescribes specific encoding.

Comment: @SergeyA: Oops. Yes, you are right. This is how they've always been stored in my experience.

Comment: @SergeyA A binary number is negative if it starts with a 1

Comment: @user6421091, more than that. Assuming your platform does 2's complement (most likely), you can read the link provided above. If you understand the code, and understand 2's complement, you'll have your answer.

Comment: @Frecklefoot, mine too. But here in C++ we prefer to stick close to Standard, unless the question itself is platform-specific.

Comment: @SergeyA I understand in the code we're dividing by 1/2^k for certain values of k but I'm having a hard time understanding the article on the wiki on two's compliment on why we can't use bitwise operators for negative numbers

Comment: When you divide a negative number by 2, it remains negative. This is true whether you're using a division operator or a right shift. Forget about the first bit for a second and consider the second bit; what happens to it?

Comment: @MarkRansom I would think the second bit would remain unchanged

Comment: This is actually a pretty good question.  Thank you for it.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is because the C++ standard states that the value resulting from the `>>` operator on negative values is implementation defined, whereas on positive values it has a result of dividing by a power of 2.

The term "implementation defined", over-simplistically, means that the standard permits the result to vary between implementations i.e. between compilers.   Among other things, that means no guarantee that it will behave in the same way as for positive values (for which the behaviour is unambiguously specified).

The reason is that the representation of a `signed` int is also implementation-defined.   This allows, for example, the usage of twos-complement representation - which (although other representations are used sometimes) is quite commonly used in practice.

Mathematically, a right shift in twos-complement is equivalent to division by a power of two with rounding down toward -infinity, not toward zero.  For a positive value, rounding toward zero and toward -infinity have the same effect (both zero and -infinity are less than any positive integral value).    For a negative value they do not (rounding is away from zero, not toward zero).

Answer (score 0):

Peter gave you an interpretation of the code based on towards which value you round. Here's another, more bitwise, one:

The successive shifts in this code are "filling in" with 1s all bit positions lower than the highest one set at the start. Let us look at that more in detail:

Let `x=0b0001 ???? ???? ????` be the binary representation of a 16 bit number, where `?` may be 0 or 1.

```
x |= x >> 1;   // x = 0b0001 ???? ???? ???? | 0b0000 1??? ???? ???? = 0b0001 1??? ???? ????
x |= x >> 2;   // x = 0b0001 1??? ???? ???? | 0b0000 011? ???? ???? = 0b0001 111? ???? ????
x |= x >> 4;   // x = 0b0001 111? ???? ???? | 0b0000 0001 111? ???? = 0b0001 1111 111? ????
x |= x >> 8;   // x = 0b0001 1111 111? ???? | 0b0000 0000 0001 1111 = 0b0001 1111 1111 1111
```

Hence the shifts are giving you the number of the form `0b00...011...1` that is only 0s then only 1s, which means a number of the form `2^n-1`. That is why you add `1` at the end, to get a power of 2. To get the correct result, you also need to remove `1` at the start, to compensate for the one you'll add at the end.

Now for negative numbers, the C++ standard does not define what the most significant bits should be when right-shifting. But whether they are `1` or `0` is irrelevant in this specific case, as long as your representation of negative numbers uses a `1` in its most significant bit position, i.e. for almost all of them.*

Because you always `or` x with itself, all those left-most bits (where the shifts differ) are going to be `or`ed with `1`s. At the end of the algorithm, you will return `0b11111...1 + 1` which in your case means `0` (because you use 2s complement, the result would be `1` in 1s complement and -2<sup>number of bits - 1</sup> + 1 in sign-magnitude).

<sub>* This holds true for the main negative numbers representations, from most to least popular: that is, 2s complement, sign-magnitude, and 1s complement. An example where this is not true is excess-K representation, which is used for IEEE floating point exponents.</sub>